# Methods to solve $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{n}\cos(x)\:dx$

Tags: integration, gamma-function, complex-integration, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

I've been playing around with the following integral and was wondering if it can be generalised to any Real $n$. Does anyone know of any methods to approach this one?

$$ I = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^n \cos(x)\:dx $$

Comment: The integral converges when $n\in(-1,0)$.

Comment: What test(s) can we use to determine convergence?

Comment: Split up $I =\int_0^1+\int_1^\infty$, the first integral converges by comparison test (with $\int \frac1{x^p}$); perform IBP on the second integral, it also converges by the same test.

Comment: You can use the same method employed in this [_answer_](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2991233/463895) by writing series of $\cos$ and then substituting $x^2=t$ we can then use Ramanujan's Master Theorem to arrive at the result needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could find its exact value via complex analysis.

> **Claim (generalization):** $\forall \alpha\in(0,1)$,$\kappa\ge0,\lambda\in\Bbb R$, 
>   $$\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\kappa x}\cos \lambda x~\mathrm dx=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{(\kappa^2+\lambda^2)^{\alpha/2}}\cos\left(\alpha \arctan\frac{\lambda}{\kappa}\right).$$

*Proof:*

Let $r=\sqrt{\kappa^2+\lambda^2},\gamma=\arctan(\lambda/\kappa)$, then $\kappa+i\lambda=re^{i\gamma}$,$-\pi/2<\gamma<\pi/2$. Consider the complex integral
\begin{align*}
\oint_Cz^{\alpha-1}e^{-rz}~\mathrm dz, \tag{1} 
\end{align*}
where $C$ is the sector contour shown as below:
[image]
We have 
\begin{align*}
\oint_Cz^{\alpha-1}e^{-rz}~\mathrm dz=&\int_\delta^R x^{\alpha-1}e^{-rz}~\mathrm dz+\int_{C_R} x^{\alpha-1}e^{-rz}~\mathrm dz\\
&+\int_R^\delta (\rho e^{i\gamma})^{\alpha-1}e^{-r\rho e^{i\gamma}}e^{i\gamma}~\mathrm d \rho+\int_{C_\delta} x^{\alpha-1}e^{-rz}~\mathrm dz=0. \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Simply we can show
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\delta\to 0}\int_{C_\delta} x^{\alpha-1}e^{-rz}~\mathrm dz=0,\qquad \lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{C_R} x^{\alpha-1}e^{-rz}~\mathrm dz=0,\tag{3}
\end{align*} 
therefore,
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha-1}e^{-rx}~\mathrm dx=e^{i\gamma\alpha}\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha-1}e^{-rxe^{i\gamma}}~\mathrm dx,\tag{4}
\end{align*}
implies
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha-1}e^{-rxe^{i\gamma}}~\mathrm dx=e^{i\gamma\alpha}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{r^\alpha}.\tag{5}
\end{align*}
By comparing real part of $(5)$, the claim is established.

---

By comparing imaginary part of $(5)$,

> $$\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\kappa x}\sin \lambda x~\mathrm dx=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{(\kappa^2+\lambda^2)^{\alpha/2}}\sin\left(\alpha \arctan\frac{\lambda}{\kappa}\right).$$

Comment: In your case: $n=\alpha-1,\kappa=0,\lambda=1$, so $$\int_0^\infty x^n\cos x~\mathrm dx=-\Gamma(n+1)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

As $\cos(x) = \Re\left[ e^{-ix}\right]$, we arrive at

$$ I = \Re \left[\int_{0}^{\infty} x^n e^{-ix} \right] $$

Applying a change of variable $u = ix$ we arrive at,

\begin{align}
   I &= \Re\left[\int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{u}{i}\right)^n e^{-u} \: \frac{1}{i}\:du\right] \\
     &=  \Re\left[ \left(\frac{1}{i}\right)^{n + 1}\int_{0}^{i\infty} u^ne^{-u}  \:du\right] 
\end{align}

Comment: you forget to change the limits of integration. If $x=\infty$ then $u=i\infty$, so the integral is not the gamma function

Comment: @Masacroso - Thank you for the pickup. I have corrected.

Comment: indeed these integrals are not convergent

Answer (score 0):

Well in order to solve that kind of integrals you may arrive this problem by IBP or if you had the knowledge about complex variable doing with the elementary tools of the residual theorem.

You can check:
[Computing the indefinite integral $\int x^n \sin x\,dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231100/computing-the-indefinite-integral-int-xn-sin-x-dx)
and:
[indefinite integral of $x^n\sin(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231028/indefinite-integral-of-xn-sinx)

Hope that those links help!

Answer (score 0):

The integrals you are trying to compute doesn't converge for $m\ge 1$. Note that

$$\left|\int_0^{2\pi n+\pi/4} x^m\cos(x)\, dx-\int_0^{2\pi n}x^m\cos(x)\, dx\right|=\left|\int_{2\pi n}^{2\pi n+\pi/4}x^m\cos(x)\, dx\right|\\=\left|\int_0^{\pi/4}(2\pi n+x)^m\cos(x)\, dx\right|\ge\frac{\sqrt 2}2\int_0^{\pi/4}(2\pi n+x)^m\, dx\ge\frac{\pi\sqrt 2}8(2\pi n)^m$$

Hence the sequence of integrals $(I_n)$ defined by

$$I_n:=\int_0^{a_n}x^m\cos(x)\, dx,\quad a_n:=\begin{cases}2\pi n,& n\text{ is even }\\2\pi(n-1)+\pi/4,&n\text{ is odd }\end{cases}$$

is not Cauchy, so the improper integral $\int_0^\infty x^m\cos(x)\, dx$ doesn't converge for $m\ge 1$.